# Is string with a value of "Error" some sort of reserved word?

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

So I have a following line of Javascript on my page:

```
form.display.value = 'Error';
```

where display is an input of type text on my page:

```
<input type="text" id="calcDisplay" name="display" maxlength="25">
```

in Chrome this works just fine making the value of the input element to be "Error". But in IE 10 and Firefox the content of the input is the following:

```
function Error() {    [native code]}
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here and why?

UPDATE: This is the actual function being called:

```
function compute(form) {
   try {
      form.display.value = eval(form.display.value);
   } catch(e) {
      form.display.value = 'Error';
   } 
}
```

And here is the video of it so you guys don't think that I'm crazy:

http://screencast.com/t/sq9xXrnf

Comment: *"Is string with a value of “Error” some sort of reserved word in Javascript?"*, Err, no, definitely not. That isn't how reserved words work. A string is a string, there are no reserved strings.

Comment: So what's causing this behavior?

Comment: How are you inspecting the value of the `display` input?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in latest Firefox.

Comment: @Jacob By looking at it on the page... I mean this is sort of a trivial example wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Marko I have no idea, I can't reproduce it, or imagine anything like it based on the code you've given. There is definitely something else at work here, the code you've posted cannot produce the symptoms you describe.

Comment: @Pointy By using your eyes? What do you mean "how?" It's there on the page.

Comment: sory @Marko but i did not get your content of the input in IE10 or firefox

Comment: @Doorknob ha ha well what I meant was, just looking at the input value, or looking at something in the debugger.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce in very simple test case.](http://jsfiddle.net/f8YRM/) Are you sure the `''` quotes are there?

Comment: @Marko I think it's likely that there's something that's setting the value to `Error` **without** quotes.

Comment: @Marko i didn't get get your content of the input in IE10 or firefox

Comment: @Doorknob I updated my question and I provided a video to demonstrate it...

Comment: `eval(form.display.value)` -- this is almost definitely a WTF. Do you really want Joe Average to execute random pieces of code in the context of your function?

Comment: How could you omit the line `form.display.value = eval(form.display.value);` from your original question?? That is **definitely** the source of your error. Nobody would have thought you were "crazy" if you'd posted this code the first time, instead of claiming such bizarre behaviour from such an innocuous line of code.

Comment: @JanDvorak Jan any suggestion then on how to do a client side calculator without using eval? How is using eval in any way dangerous in my app considering the fact that purpose is a simple calculator?

Comment: @Marko given that the user can type in random valid variable names by accident, he can break the calculator without even knowing. Reading them is one thing, but once he discovers he can assign, you have unleashed a monster best described as a "blind bull in a china shop". Something's bound to happen and he will blame you.

Comment: At the very least, you could use `new Function` (or indirect `eval`) and isolate the possible damage to the global scope only. Or, you could use a web worker (like [our bot](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1839506/caprica-six) does) to isolate the scope even further. Or, you could use a math expression parsing library and not have the problem of arbitrary code execution at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value `Error` is already in the input, this line:

```
form.display.value = eval(form.display.value);
```

...is going to evaluate to the function `Error` you defined earlier. So this must be happening on a second call to your `compute` function.

Note that browsers are inconsistent with how `eval` works, which is why you see browser differences.

Comment: Putting aside the fact that the OP shouldn't `eval` arbitrary input in the first place.

Comment: @Doorknob Any suggestion then on how to do a client side calculator without using eval? How is using eval in any way dangerous in my app considering the fact that purpose is a simple calculator?